# How to calculate the velocity of an ideal non-viscous fluid through a pipe when the pressure difference between its ends are known?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

For example:- *velocity of a fluid through a pipe joining two containers kept on a plane, each having the fluid at different heights ; When it just starts to flow from one to another.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Maybe by adding more information or attaching an image of the described problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.